# Retrieved row values from query to textboxes

Tags: c#, mysql, textbox, rows

How can I put the values retrieved from a query that contains ONE COLUMN and MULTIPLE ROWS to textboxes. What i mean is txtBox1 will have the value of the first row, txtBox2 will have the value of the second row and so on. What I know is how to retrieve values of each column but not rows.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code, please, which retrieves your data.

Comment: How do you know that your TextBoxes are enough for all the rows?

Comment: I havent tried anything yet coz im really clueless on what to do. The number of data inside the database is finite and cannot be changed or you cannot add any data anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
List<TextBox> allTextBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
int current = -1;
using (var con = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT ColumnName FROM dbo.TableName", con))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rd.Read() && ++current < allTextBoxes.Count)
            {
                allTextBoxes[current].Text = rd.GetString(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

replace `this.Controls` with the container control that contains all of your `TextBox`es.

Comment: I've tried .GetString() but it only retrieves the first row and all textbox will have the value from the first row not from their respective rows. How will I be able to retrieve the second row onward?

Comment: @AfricaKen: note that i've edited my answer `current = -1` instead of `current = 0`. How many TextBoxes are in `Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList()`?

Comment: There are 8 rows in the database and 8 textboxes.

Comment: @AfricaKen You either have to go with `Array TextBoxes` or with this idea.

Comment: @AfricaKen: again, how many TextBoxes are in `Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList()`? Maybe they are in a different container control(f.e. a `Panel`), then use that. The code above loops either until all available textboxes are filled or all records are read.

Comment: Pulled your while statement then changed few variables and it worked. Thanks. :D